# @OneToOne Problem after Dropwizard (and Hibernate) Update

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard, one-to-one

I'm struggling with a Dropwizard update. Mainly with a resulting Hibernate problem.

I have several @OneToOne relations in my model. Really simple. But after the upgrade to DropWizard 4 (from 2.x) there is a new Hibernate in town. (Hibernate 6). With that I get an exception on loading the dependent object:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.Fetch.createAssembler(org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.FetchParentAccess, org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AssemblerCreationState)\" because \"versionFetch\" is null
org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.<init>(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:158)
org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityResultInitializer.<init>(EntityResultInitializer.java:34)
org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityResultImpl.lambda$createResultAssembler$0(EntityResultImpl.java:105)
org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper$1.resolveInitializer(ResultsHelper.java:97)
org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityResultImpl.createResultAssembler(EntityResultImpl.java:96)
org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.StandardJdbcValuesMapping.resolveAssemblers(StandardJdbcValuesMapping.java:53)
org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.ResultsHelper.createRowReader(ResultsHelper.java:67)
org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:422)
org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166)
org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91)
org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.DatabaseSnapshotExecutor.loadDatabaseSnapshot(DatabaseSnapshotExecutor.java:187)
org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderSupport.loadDatabaseSnapshot(SingleIdEntityLoaderSupport.java:39)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getDatabaseSnapshot(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2088)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getDatabaseSnapshot(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:331)
org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:305)
org.hibernate.event.internal.EntityState.getEntityState(EntityState.java:59)
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:88)
```

The entity is not very special:

```
@Entity(name = "EntityA")
@Table(name = "Entity_A")
public class EntityA extends AbstractEntity {

...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "referenceA", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private EntityB referencingB;
...
}
```

the other side is as simple:

```
@Entity(name = "EntityB")
@Table(name = "Entity_B")
public class EntityB extends AbstractEntity {
 

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_ENTITY_A_2_ENTITY_B"))
    @Nullable
    private EntityA referencingA;
...
}
```

Both classes inherit from a common father which carries the id and version:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

 @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false)
    private UUID guid;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
    private int version;
...
```

To fix this problem I removed the @Version annotation. Then the server starts, but the optimistic locking isn't working.  :-(

I tried several different @OneToOne definitions and @JoinColumn definitions. Non was working. :-(

I upgraded Hibernate to the latest 6.2.1 version :-(

I removed the @Nullable annotation :-(

With the "old" Hibernate version everything worked. And I can't find my problem. Any hints?

THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

FYI I've encountered the same issue and adding CascadeType.ALL to the parent Entity fixed the issue.
It seems that upon deletion Hibernate SELECT all Entities referencing our Parent Entity and having it deleted without removing the reference from the Children bugs it out.

In your case

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "referenceA", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private EntityB referencingB;
```

Add it to this one.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, unfortunately :(